# Writable stream finished?

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I'm trying to implement a writable stream in Node.js. I was reading through SubStack's [excellent stream handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook#creating-a-writable-stream). I was wondering whether there's a way to find out inside the writable stream when the read stream has stopped writing (when it calls *push(null)*)? Is it OK for the implementation of a writable stream to subscribe to the *finish* event?

Answer (score 1):

No reason why not subscribe to `end` event. It's in the contract, regardless of who consumes it.

Some of the streams referenced in the handbook you mention do that themselves. For example:

https://github.com/Raynos/duplexer/blob/master/index.js#L36